Manga where mc gets killed in an accident when he wants to buy something for his sister and reincarnated into another world
I'm searching for a manga where the main character reincarnated after getting killed in an accident when he wants to buy something for his sister or something like that. And in further chapter, we discovered that his sister follows the mc into the same world by ending herself. I believed that it has typical romance.

I've read it a long time ago so the description might be false.

After searching for a while, I've found the manga that I want called "Seichou Cheat de Nandemo Dekiru you ni Natta ga, Mushoku dake wa Yamerarenai you desu". The description is wrong because he actually killed when going to a job interview.

Don't forget you can self accept in 45 hours but clicking on the checkmark.
